# How to pass a variable generated from foreach loop to another page in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, variables, foreach

I have a page to get user event_id which is then used to retrieve all user_id and info associated with that event_id from mysql. Then, the data is displayed in a table with one row representing one user. So, now I would like to display additional info of a particular user when user click on that user in another page.

This is an example of the codes to illustrate what I was trying to work on. The codes might not be as accurate as actual code is too long for display.

main.php

```
<form name="input" method="post">    
    <input type="text" id="event_id" name = "event_id" value = "" /><br>
   <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" />    
</form>

//$user_main is an associative array generated when event_id
//is entered into input text box and user click submit
 <?php $user_main = array(); ?>

<table>
    <?php
    //Loop through and print all user_id associated with event_id entered
    foreach(user_main as main)
    { ?>
    <tr>User ID: <?php echo $main['user_id'];?></tr>
    <tr>User Name: <?php echo $main['user_name'];?></tr>
    <tr>User Info: <a href = "display.php">Contact</a></tr>
    <?php } ?>
</table>
```

display.php

```
//Pass user_id to display.php page that correspond to the user id clicked
user_id = {{ 111 }}

//retrieve contact info from mysql for user_id = 111 and display below
<table>
    <tr>User ID: </tr>
    <tr>Mobile: </tr>
    <tr>Address: </tr>
    <tr>Email: </tr>
</table>
```

My question is how to pass a variable to another page. For example, if a user click on the link for user_id = 111, how do I pass the value '111' to display.php page so I can retrieve data from mysql to display the info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For such kind of tasks URI parameters are very commonly used. You can make use of the `$_GET` superglobal in that case.

```
<tr>User Info: <a href = "display.php?userid=<?php echo $main['user_id'];?>">Contact</a></tr>
```

In your `display.php` you can then access the variable like this:

```
<?php
echo $_GET['userid'];
```

From now on it should be clear. You can fetch the record based on your `$_GET` data. Don't forget to add extra security here. You should never trust user input.

This is pretty basic stuff so, I suggest you read up a bit on superglobals until you feel confident.

- http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

Comment: Thanks. I self taught myself php from scratch and it's still very new to me at this point. I only had 1-2 weeks of going through online tutorials before jumping into php projects and laravel at the same time.

Comment: You're welcome. Your question was well formulated and you put some effort into it.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution that comes to my mind is just pass user id along with the `url` as an argument. This obviously assumes that the `user_id` value is not confidential. So if you define the `href` tag like this:

```
<tr>User Info: <a href = "display.php?id="<?php echo $main['user_id'];?>>Contact</a></tr>
```

In `display.php` you could get a hold of that `id` by doing something like:

```
$user_id = $_GET["id"]; //And do the relevant database lookups and display the info
```

If however, you want to pass the `user_id` so that it's not visible in the address bar of the browser, you could make a simple `post` request and pass the relevant `user_id` in that request. Hope it gets you started in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

```
<tr>User Info: <a href = "display.php">Contact</a></tr>
```

change this line to this

```
<tr>User Info: <a href = "display.php?id=<?php $main['user_id']?>">Contact</a></tr>
```

Than you can run your query in isset function.

```
<?php 

isset($_GET['id'])
{
    $id=$_GET['id'];

    //Run your query here, include $id in where clause in your query
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On the page that PHP posts to, use the `$_REQUEST` or `$_POST` variables to get the data.
For example, on your display page, you could use `$event_id = $_REQUEST["event_id"]`

Answer (score 0):

As you are referring , Get or Request variables can be used in php.

***The GET method*** sends the encoded user information appended to the page request. The page and the encoded information are separated by the ? character.
for example

`www.example.com/display.php?id='111'`

and retrieve it in the `display.php` as `$_GET['id']`
he $_REQUEST variable

***The PHP $_REQUEST*** variable contains the contents of both `$_GET, $_POST, and $_COOKIE`.
The PHP `$_REQUE`ST variable can be used to get the result from form data sent with both the GET and POST methods.